# How to prevent the pyqt button's clicked signal from sending Boolean value when slot functions have a decorator?

Tags: python, qt

I am building a QT project with qt designer and pyqt5. I have one button that sends a signal with a boolean value.
My code to bind the signal and function(my decorator is inside the class, but it shouldn't be a problem with my decorator, because no matter what decorator is used, the clicked signal will pass in the bool parameter):

```py
class Demo:
    def __init__(self):
        # bind the signal and function
        ...
        self.ui.pushButton_disconnect.clicked.connect(
            self.robot.disconnect_devices
        )
        ...
    def my_decorator(func):
        def wrapper(self,*args,**kwargs):
            '''
            args and kwargs is necessary 
            because other decorated functions have parameters
            '''
            # do something
            return func(self,*args,**kwargs)
        retrun wrapper
    # function
    @my_decorator
    def disconnect_devices(self, *args):
        print(args)
        # do something
```

Now I have to use `*args` to receive `False`. I know that using `lambda` in `connect` can also avoid this issue.
I have found the reason: I am using a decorator to decorate the function `disconnect_devices`, it seems that clicked signal will automatically pass in parameters because `*args` is used in the decorator, so I have to use `*args` to in my function. Is there a way to avoid this? Or can I fix the `clicked` signal as a signal without parameters?

Comment: See [ask]. Post a [mre] including the implementation of the ```my_decorator()```.

Comment: It's still not a [mre] and not clear. Why not remove the ```args``` and ```kwargs``` arguments when you call the ```func()``` inside the ```wrapper()```?

Comment: Because this decorator needs to decorate many functions, some of which have (different) parameters, while others do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't modify the signature of the `QAbstractButton::clicked` signal.

Instead, you can create a new decorator wrapping the original decorator like this.

```
...
def my_decorator(func):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

def my_decorator_ignoring_args(func):
    return my_decorator(lambda self, *_: func(self))

class Demo:
    ...
    @my_decorator_ignoring_args
    def disconnect_devices(self):
        ...
...
```

Also, you can define only single decorator and wrap the decorated function if it has no parameters, like this.

```
import inspect
...
def my_decorator(func):
    if len(inspect.signature(func).parameters) == 1:
        original_func = func
        func = lambda self, *_: original_func(self)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

class Demo:
    ...
    @my_decorator
    def disconnect_devices(self):
        ...
```

Comment: The second solution didn't works. I guess the simplest way is to use lambda when binding slot functions. `self.ui.pushButton_disconnect.clicked.connect(lambda: self.robot.disconnect_devices())`

Comment: @肉蛋充肌, check the updated answer. I tested before with a function, not an instance method. You need to correct the sample code in your answer for the [mre] guide.

Comment: Both two solutions work well! Thanks a lot!